# Sublime Text 3 REPL stops accepting input after running plt.show()

Tags: python, matplotlib, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

After running this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel("Some numbers")
plt.show(block=False)
```

A graph correctly displays the expected output. However, even after closing the graph the REPL console no longer accepts input. If I run a script again, it works, but the REPL console doesn't **even if the new script doesn't use matplotlib.**

What's going on/how do I get REPL to wake up and start working again?

Answer (score 0):

I found a very unsatisfying "solution". You can open an iPython REPL (Tools > SublimeREPL > Python > Python - IPython) and afterwards transfer your code there (Tools > SublimeREPL > Transfer to REPL > File). If I hit enter, I can close the graph and keep the REPL interactive. [This is what it looks like for me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grHRg.png)

It's okay for your minimal example, but to be honest I wouldn't want to use it on large chunks of code. If anybody found a real solution, I would be happy to know.